# Rotating an image to specific direction

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to rotate an arrow to point to some specific location

```
  float bearing = myLoc.bearingTo(mecca);
      RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, bearing, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
      arrow.setAnimation(rotate);
      rotate.start();
```

However it rotates and within less than one second it comes to its original place. How can i make it rotate like a compass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple way to rotate an imageView :

```
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
arrow.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Comment: bearing is angle i suppose but how will i get PivX and pivY

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried :

```
rotate.setFillAfter(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try To set Duration Of Your Animation, like

```
animation.setDuration(1500);
Where Duration is int(miliseconds)
```